# ajax validation with multiple input fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a new system and am stuck at a point with jquery + ajax.
My problem is this, how can i validate multiple fields in my registration form using ajax. I don't want to create a separate validation for each input fields.

can you help me guys, please. :-(

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many jQuery plugins for this problem.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ Is this what you need?

Give [jQuery plugin page](http://plugins.jquery.com/) a visit.